# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 759 of the JSON data

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

Following is my php file.

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    include 'dbconnection.php';

    //$serviceType = (isset($_POST["type"])?Trim($_POST["type"]):"");
    $JOBNO = (isset($_POST["JOBNO"])?Trim($_POST["JOBNO"]):"");
    $JOBSEQ = (isset($_POST["JOBSEQ"])?Trim($_POST["JOBSEQ"]):"");
    $HBLNO = (isset($_POST["HBLNO"])?Trim($_POST["HBLNO"]):"");
    $MBLNO = (isset($_POST["MBLNO"])?Trim($_POST["MBLNO"]):"");
    $CREF = (isset($_POST["CREF"])?Trim($_POST["CREF"]):"");

    $sql = "select * from VWJOBDET WHERE (JOBNO = :jobno or :jobno is null) and (JOBSEQNO = :jobseq or  :jobseq is null)
            and (MBL = :mblno or :mblno is null) and (HAWBHBL = :hblno or :hblno is null) and (CUSTREF = :cref or :cref is null)";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':jobno',$JOBNO,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':jobseq',$JOBSEQ,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':mblno',$MBLNO,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':hblno',$HBLNO,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':cref',$CREF,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    //$data = array();
    foreach($query as $row) {
         echo json_encode($row); 
    }

    exit;   
?>
```

JS file tracking.js

```
function  searchEngine() {
    //alert("enters");  
    localStorage.lpage="Shipment Tracking";
    var jno = document.getElementById('jobno').value;
    var jseq = document.getElementById('jobseq').value;
    var mbl = document.getElementById('mblno').value;
    var hbl = document.getElementById('hblno').value;
    var cf = document.getElementById('cref').value;
    var Var_jno=jno.toUpperCase();
    var Var_jseq=jseq.toUpperCase();
    var Var_mbl=mbl.toUpperCase();
    var Var_hbl=hbl.toUpperCase();
    var Var_cf=cf.toUpperCase();

    var postStat=$.post('http://localhost/ipack/tracking.php',{'JOBNO':Var_jno,'JOBSEQ':Var_jseq,'MBLNO':Var_mbl,'HBLNO':Var_hbl,'CREF':Var_cf,},
    function (jsonVal)
    {

         obj = JSON.parse(jsonVal);
        console.log(obj.ORIGIN);
    })  
    window.location.href = '#Viewbl';   

}
```

index.html

```
<div data-role="content"  style=" margin-top:1%; margin-bottom:10%;" align="center"> <!--Content-->
                <div style="width:50%" align="right">
                    <input type="text" name="jobno" id="jobno" value="" placeholder="Enter Job No: "  data-theme="a"/>
                    <input type="text" name="jobseq" id="jobseq" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Sequence No: "  data-theme="a"/>
                    <input type="text" name="mblno" id="mblno" value="" placeholder="Enter Master AWB/BL No: "  data-theme="a"/>
                    <input type="text" name="hblno" id="hblno" value="" placeholder="Enter House AWB/BL No: "  data-theme="a"/>
                    <input type="text" name="cref" id="cref" value="" placeholder="Enter Client Reference No: "  data-theme="a"/>
                    <button onClick="javascript: searchEngine()" >Search</button>
                    <button type="reset" onClick="javascript: refreshEngine()" >Reset</button>
                </div>

            </div>
```

While i am pressing search button, in mozilla console shows an error like:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 759 of the JSON data.

And also getting muliple value on my json output.
This is my json output:

{"INTJOBNO":"351","0":"351","JOBNO":"HGB/0003/2015","1":"HGB/0003/2015","JOBSEQNO":"0","2":"0","JOBTYPE":"OFI","3":"OFI","CUSTREF":null,"4":null,"HAWBHBL":"352-15-02345-352628","5":"456-15-02345-6768","MBL":"ME-GH67676767","6":"ME-EFGH0001","JOBTYPEDESC":"Ocean Freight Import","7":"Ocean Freight Import","PKGS":"5","8":"5","VOLUME":"7.333","9":"7.333","WEIGHT":"1148","10":"1148","ORIGIN":"SOUTHAMPTON","11":"SOUTHAMPTON","DESTINATION":"JEBEL ALI","12":"JEBEL ALI","ETD":"09-JUN-15","13":"09-JUN-15","ETA":"26-JUN-15","14":"26-JUN-15","SHIPMENTSTATUS":null,"15":null,"STATDATE":null,"16":null,"CUSTOMER":"CU0010","17":"CU0010","CUSTOMERNAME":"asdasdas AB","18":"FAGERHULTS BELYSNING AB","SHIPPER":null,"19":null,"SHIPPERNAME":null,"20":null}

{"INTJOBNO":"361","0":"361","JOBNO":"OFC/0005/2015","1":"OFC/0005/2015","JOBSEQNO":"0","2":"0","JOBTYPE":"OFC","3":"OFC","CUSTREF":null,"4":null,"HAWBHBL":"352-15-02345-345456","5":"352-15-02345-352628","MBL":"ME-EJ011008","6":"ME-EJ011008","JOBTYPEDESC":"Ocean Freight Clearance","7":"Ocean Freight Clearance","PKGS":"5","8":"5","VOLUME":"7.333","9":"7.333","WEIGHT":"1148","10":"1148","ORIGIN":"LONDON","11":"LONDON","DESTINATION":"JEBEL ALI","12":"JEBEL ALI","ETD":"09-JUN-15","13":"09-JUN-15","ETA":null,"14":null,"SHIPMENTSTATUS":null,"15":null,"STATDATE":null,"16":null,"CUSTOMER":"CU0010","17":"CU1110","CUSTOMERNAME":"adsasff AB","18":"hjkhjkhjk AB","SHIPPER":null,"19":null,"SHIPPERNAME":null,"20":null}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format the error message in blockquote - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Also, please refrain from adding non-constructive text such as 'help please' and 'thank you', although your kindness is always appreciated, they are not necessary in order to attract answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use fetch statement to get data after query execute function

```
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($data);
```

NOTE:-

`$query->fetchAll();` will return both numeric and associative array, if you want only *associative array* use `$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` or if you want only *numeric array* of data use `$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);`

for more reference [pdo-fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

**From your code**

```
foreach($query as $row) {
         echo json_encode($row); 
    }
```

printing json result multiple time which is wrong, collect all the data as array then finally echo json data i.e.

```
$result = []
foreach($query->fetch() as $row) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: @VipinKA its my pleasure, can you make it accept answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->execute();
echo json_encode($query->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Its getting mutipple values on json.